# Signature set did not satisfy policy :- Issue in updating anchor peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I had created a network with two organization(Org1,Org2) in the channel using the fabric version 1.4.4.I have added one more organization to the channel.After adding the new organization to the channel,I am trying to update anchor peer based on this reference https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#updating-the-channel-config-to-include-an-org3-anchor-peer-optional .

But it raises error while trying to sign the update transaction using Org3.

```
  Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing 
  channel 'masterchannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for 
  [Group]  /Channel/Application/Org3MSP not satisfied: signature set did not satisfy 
  policy
```

Could anyone help me to resolve the error in anchor updation?

Answer (score 0):

The error regarding the signature set policy is due to the invalid signature for the  `peer channel update` request.

As per the signature set policy in configtx.yaml file,anchor peer updation requires the signature from admin.

```
Organizations:
  - &Org3
      Name: Org3MSP
      ID: Org3MSP
      MSPDir: 'crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.co/msp'
      Policies:
           Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('Org3.admin')"
```

Since the anchor peer update is only an update to Org3 we only need to have Org3 sign off on the update.So you must confirm the environment variables before the signing process.